# AngularJS Ajax call exception handling

Tags: angularjs

I just start learning AngularJS. I don't know where to find a tutorial to arm myself with a knowledge of dealing an exception in the following code:

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$modalInstance', 'entity', 'MyEntity',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $modalInstance, entity, MyEntity) {
  ...
    var onSaveFinished = function (result) {
        $scope.$emit('myApp:myEntityUpdate', result);
        $modalInstance.close(result);
    };
  $scope.save = function () {

   MyEntity.save($scope.myEntity, onSaveFinished);  <-- an exception can occur on this line
```

I need to catch any exception on an Ajax call and display an error accordingly on the html file. I have tried using .catch and .error without a luck of catching an exception.

Can someone point a direction on where to learn a knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Does `myEntity.save` return the promise? If you use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you should be able to use `.error()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [$exceptionHandler service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). That's what Angular's docs say:

> Any uncaught exception in angular expressions is delegated to this service. The default implementation simply delegates to $log.error which logs it into the browser console.

To add your  own exception handling, you should override the normal action of $exceptionHandler (example in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)).